# Renomear arquivos com Python, adicionando numeração de forma dinâmica

Tags: python, arquivo, script

Tenho um diretório com muitas listas pdf, e quero renomear os arquivos de forma dinâmica.

Ex:

```
~/teste/

|__ProjMed-Química-Físico.Química-quimica_propriedades_coligativas_exercicios.pdf

|__ProjMed-Química-Físico.Química-quimica_termoquimica_entalpia_lei_de_hess_energia_de_ligacao_exercicios_gabarito.pdf
```

Até agora, meu código está assim:

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/matheus/teste/')
for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_id, f_subject, f_frente, f_topic = f_name.split('-')
    f_name1 = '{}-{}-{}-{}{}'.format(f_id, f_subject, f_frente, f_topic, f_ext)
    print(f_name1)
# print(sorted(f_name1, key=str))
```

como se pode notar em *f_id*, sempre haverá um identificador repetido. no caso do exemplo, 'ProjMed'.

eu gostaria de contar quantos ProjMed aparecem (total de arquivos com este identificador) e renomeá-los de forma que fique algo assim:

1-ProjMed-***

2-ProjMed-***

3-ProjMed-***

etc..

estou tentando fazer um script que rode toda vez que um novo arquivo for adicionado em uma pasta. (seria ativado com o *incron*, do Linux) então, no dia a dia, existirão alguns arquivos que já tem uma numeração e outros que ainda devem ter a numeração adicionada (sempre 1 a mais que o maior valor já presente em outro arquivo). Logicamente, se já houver algum arquivo com numeração, ele deve ser ignorado na renomeação.

como eu poderia modificar meu script atual para alcançar esses objetivos?

- Contar quantos '*identificadores*' aparecem por pasta ('ProjMed', por exemplo)
- ignorar a renomeação de arquivos que já possuem numeração
- renomear arquivos sem numeração com *n+1*, sendo *n* a maior numeração presente em um arquivo desta pasta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

segue uma proposta de solução para o seu problema.

Pra facilitar principalmente a nomeação do arquivo foi feita a seguinte classe:

```
class fileDataModel:
    def __init__(self, id_name, subject, frente, topic, ext, id_num = 0):
        self.id_num = id_num
        self.id_name = id_name
        self.subject = subject
        self.frente = frente
        self.topic = topic
        self.ext = ext

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.getFileName()

    def getFileName(self):
        if self.id_num != 0:
            return "{}-{}-{}-{}-{}{}".format(self.id_num, self.id_name, self.subject, self.frente, self.topic, self.ext)
        return "{}-{}-{}-{}{}".format(self.id_name, self.subject, self.frente, self.topic, self.ext)
```

Note que o método `getFileName` retorna strings diferentes dependendo do valor do `id_num`. Foi considerado que quando o `id_num` é igual a 0, o arquivo e novo e ainda não possui numeração.

Agora segue uma proposta para numeração automática de novos arquivos:

```
import os

os.chdir('/home/matheus/teste/')

files = dict()
for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_name = f_name.split('-')

    f_id_num = 0

    if len(f_name) == 4: # Arquivo sem identificador
        f_id, f_subject, f_frente, f_topic = f_name
    elif len(f_name) == 5: # Arquivo ja com identificador
        f_id_num, f_id, f_subject, f_frente, f_topic = f_name
        f_id_num = int(f_id_num)
    else:
        print(f"Arquivo com nome fora do padrao: {f}")
        continue

    newFileDataModel = fileDataModel(f_id, f_subject, f_frente, f_topic, f_ext, f_id_num)

    if f_id not in files.keys():
        files[f_id] = {'last_id' : f_id_num, 'files' : [newFileDataModel]}
    else:
        files[f_id]['files'].append(newFileDataModel)
        if f_id_num > files[f_id]['last_id']:
            files[f_id]['last_id'] = f_id_num

for key in files.keys():

    last_id = files[key]['last_id']

    for file in files[key]['files']:
        if file.id_num != 0:
            continue

        last_id += 1

        old_file_name = file.getFileName()
        file.id_num = last_id

        os.rename(old_file_name, file.getFileName())
```

Vale ressaltar que o código acima sempre considera o id mais alto presente nos arquivos adicionados. Ou seja, caso o id mais alto seja 4, um novo arquivo terá id igual a 5. Além disso, se houver deleção de algum arquivo com id inferior ao maior id, um novo arquivo adicionado não será contemplado com esse id faltante na sequência e sim com um número a mais do que o id mais alto presente.

Comment: Dica - de uma olhada na pathlib do Python - o código acima pode ficar bem mais simples e consistente. Também fica mais fácil evitar o uso de `chdir` que não é confiável. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html (ignore a primeira sessão na documentação - e vá direto  para o "Basic Use" - a primeira parte fica diletando sobre "que classe usar para manipular um path de Windows se seu programa está no Linux" e só é útil em sistemas muito sofisticados)